# Using Tiles with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles

I'm just trying to Learn Tiles with Spring MVC. I haven't used Tiles Before. Please find the code attached:

**servlet.xml**

`<context:component-scan base-package="org.sparsham.sparshammanagement.controllers" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>`

---

**My Tiles.xml**

`<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/pages/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/pages/layout/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/pages/layout/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/layout/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>`

---

Then I created layout headers and footers.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")

public class Default {

    @RequestMapping("index")
    public String index(){
        return "Sparsham";
    }

    @RequestMapping("*")
    public String unhandled(){
        return "error404";
    }
}
```

---

What is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a default layout. Now you need to define definition for your view in tiles config file. Like:

```
<definition name="Sparsham" extends="base.definition">
     <put-attribute name="title" value="Contact Manager" />
     <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/Sparsham.jsp" />
</definition>
```